# Help: ATA disk header failed

Tags: hard-disk, manjaro

My disk is no longer recognized by the boot, here is the result of its analysis, I am a little lost:
/dev/sdc:

```
attempting to set PIO mode to 0
 HDIO_SET_PIO_MODE failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error
 HDIO_GET_MULTCOUNT failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: No message of desired type
 HDIO_GET_BUSSTATE failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[manjaro manjaro]# hdparm --verbose /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
outgoing cdb:  85 08 0e 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 ec 00
SG_IO: ATA_16 status=0x0, host_status=0x4, driver_status=0x0
SG_IO: bad host status: 0x4
Trying legacy HDIO_DRIVE_CMD
outgoing cdb:  85 08 0e 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 a1 00
SG_IO: ATA_16 status=0x0, host_status=0x4, driver_status=0x0
SG_IO: bad host status: 0x4
Trying legacy HDIO_DRIVE_CMD
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error
 IO_support    =  1 (32-bit)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 0/255/63, sectors = 0, start = 0
```